# CSS styling navigation buttons

Tags: html, css, positioning

You can see an attempt at what I'm trying to do here: http://rjlacount.com/clients/GreenTree/

I want the navigation li's to determine padding automatically so they can stretch across the entire width of the inner wrapper. So, if I added another li or took one out, they would still be centered and the padding of each li would just increase/decrease to make up for it.

Right now I'm floating the last navigation li to the right and adding padding to each one to try to get it as close to full-length as possible. So it's almost how I want it to look, but I have a space between the last two items that I'd like to get rid of.

Is this possible? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Might be work checking out this jQuery plugin to achieve what you want: http://exscale.se/archives/2007/11/09/jquery-full-width-navigation-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this will work in < IE8, but you could always provide a `float` or `display: inline-block` fallback to those browsers using a conditional stylesheet.

#### Example

[image: Example]

#### CSS

```
ul {
    display: table; 
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/A9rek/).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/A9rek/1/) with one more `li`, you'll notice the CSS is constant :P

Comment: @alex... you always beat me to the punch :) well answered +1

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is almost exactly what I need, but one more quick clarification... is there a way to make each cell taller while keeping each as a big button? I tried adding padding to each li, but only a small section of each was actually selectable on hover. I basically want them to be big buttons the user can click any area of.